# Usage of metafor package - order of terms

Tags: meta-analysis

My question might be too simple but I couldn´t figure out the answer online or by only reading the help function of metafor package. While conducting a meta-analysis trough escalc function what is the correct order for both test and control variables?

The code I´m trying to use is this:

es_mean<-escalc(measure ="SMD", m1i=Clear_mean, sd1i=Clear_dev, n1i=Clear_n, m2i=turbid_mean, sd2i=turbid_dev, n2i=turbid_n, data = effect_chl, append = T, vtype="LS")

Clear is my control environment and turbid corresponds to the effect I´m testing for. Is this the correct way to use this function, I mean, are m1, sd1 and n1 used for control and m2, sd2 and n2 used for what I´m testing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

For `measure="SMD"`, the `escalc()` function puts `m1i-m2i` in the numerator (which is divided by the pooled standard deviation). It is up to you to decide what you want `m1i` and `m2i` to represent. For example, if large values of the mean are a "good" thing, then using `m1i` for the treatment and `m2i` for the control group means would lead to values above 0 if the treatment is working (assuming that increasing the mean is the goal of the treatment).

Comment: And what about the interpretation of estimate and p-value given by the test? My model returned: Estimate: -0,32 and p-value = 0,003. Does it allow me to say that my treatment has a negative and significant effect on the variable?

Comment: I know nothing about your data, analysis, model, etc., so I cannot help with this. This aside, this is a different question.

Comment: @PatriciaNunes can you not just look at your data to see which condition has the larger mean on average?